# Subclassed UITableViewHeaderFooterView height not registering

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom **UITableViewHeaderFooterView** with a **UIImageView**, and two **UILabels**:

```
class CustomHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView
```

This is being set like so in the table view:

```
tableHeaderView = CustomHeaderView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: 190), reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

The table view being set is in a grouped table view with static cells. This all works totally fine but for some reason the height of the header view does not register and the cells in the table view overlap the custom header view. Can anyone suggest something I can do to make this work so that the cells don't overlap?

Comment: Doesn't the UITa leViewDelegate control the height for the tables cells?

Comment: @Freddy Does the **UITableViewDelegate** control the height of the **TableHeaderView**?

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying. HeightForHeaderInSection. Look at the documentation titled *modifying the header and footers section*

Comment: You can also set a constant height on the UITableView - `sectionHeaderHeight` property if you don't want to add it into the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

I set the header height like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
        return 200
    }

    return 0
}
```